# Object saved using saveRDS not identical to the original?

Tags: r, rdata

I saved a `data.table` named `dat` using `saveRDS` and then read the saved object to a new variable named `u`. I expected the two to be identical, upon checking, here's what I found:

```
> identical(u$type, dat$type)
[1] TRUE
> identical(u$degc, dat$degc)
[1] TRUE
> identical(u$rh, dat$rh)
[1] TRUE
> identical(u$pres, dat$pres)
[1] TRUE
> identical(u$prec, dat$prec)
[1] TRUE
> identical(u$tme, dat$tme)
[1] TRUE
> identical(u, dat)
[1] FALSE
```

If all the columns are identical, and the column names are the same, why are the two not identical?

**DATA**

This should be reproducible with most datasets but here's a sample of what I have just in case:

```
> dput(dat[1:20])
structure(list(tme = structure(c(1512489600, 1512493200, 1512496800, 
1512500400, 1512504000, 1512507600, 1512511200, 1512514800, 1512518400, 
1512522000, 1512525600, 1512529200, 1512532800, 1512536400, 1512540000, 
1512543600, 1512547200, 1512550800, 1512554400, 1512558000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago"), degc = c(24, 21, 21, 19, 
18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 14, 13, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 10, 9, 9), 
    rh = c(89, 87, 88, 82, 81, 79, 76, 80, 80, 80, 78, 75, 71, 
    68, 67, 68, 71, 76, 78, 80), type = c("forecast_1", "forecast_1", 
    "forecast_1", "forecast_1", "forecast_1", "forecast_1", "forecast_1", 
    "forecast_1", "forecast_1", "forecast_1", "forecast_1", "forecast_1", 
    "forecast_1", "forecast_1", "forecast_1", "forecast_1", "forecast_1", 
    "forecast_1", "forecast_1", "forecast_1"), pres = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), prec = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("tme", 
"degc", "rh", "type", "pres", "prec"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000000b0788>)
```

Comment: Have you tried `all.equal` to get more information?

Comment: Note the `.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000000b0788>` attribute. That's a pointer to a memory location where the object is stored. If you re-load a file from an RDS it will not go back to the same memory location so data.tables will differ due to the pointer address. So while they may have the same data in them, they are stored in different places so are not identical. You wouldn't have the same issue with plain data.frames.

Comment: I'm not sure *why*, but using `identical(..., ignore.environment = TRUE)` seems to get around the issue.

Comment: @MrFlick That's a good point - I don't know a lot about how R saves data (usign pointers or makes copies etc.) Useful to know especially if a change to one object can modify another (when pointing to the same memory location). I'll definitely investigate this further.

Comment: @neilfws `all.equal` returns `TRUE` 
@Gregor `identical(u, dat, ignore.environment = T)` returns `FALSE`